# Get the passed duration in years from a Date field in apex

Tags: apex, date

I figured that I can retrieve the number of the passed years since a `Date field` by usin formula, but what if I want to do this in `apex class`.

I have a `date field` that I want to calculate the number of years from, and return it as `integer`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an apex code that solved the problem

```
Date production_d = product.Date__c;
Date current_date = date.today();

Decimal years = (production_d.daysBetween(current_date ))/365.25; // days to years
return years.round(System.RoundingMode.DOWN); // return Integer
```

Comment: Except, it's not 365.25. It's closer to 365.242, and changes every year. The difference would make a difference for dates very far apart. A better idea would be to calculate the day as a literal number (366*year+31*(0-based month)+(0-based day). Subtract the two values, then divide by 366, and you're good.